# How to plot the lognormal distribution in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I have a dataset where I want to plot the lognormal distribution of the 'radius_in_nm' which has the float numbers. I have doubts about the solutions defined on the Internet. Here is what I did but I am not sure why we give 10000 the size where len(df) is 2211.

```
mu, sigma = 1.3332213737385599,  1.2572129222891426
# why we used the random?
s = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 10000)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 10,
                            density=True, 
                            color='blue')
x = np.linspace(min(bins),
            max(bins), 10000)

pdf = (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
   / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))

plt.plot(x, pdf, color='black')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

and I got this result which is not so good.
[image]

how to make x-axis and y-axis a number between 1-10 and 1-200

Comment: You don't use `df` in your code.  You seem to have copied a piece of code you found on the internet, and want us to explain it for you.  Thats pretty off topic for stackoverflow...

Comment: This is my question, why they don't use the df, and where I should add the df.

Comment: If I add instead of 10000, the df, I get this error `ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 2211`

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html  `lognormal` is a random number generator that is making fake data.